# ¿Cómo ejecutar un comando y, si falla, volverlo a lanzar? En la consola de GNU/linux

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

Novato aquí. Gracias desde ya por cualquier respuesta.

Estoy descargando desde un servidor problemático usando axel, y me gustaría que si el mismo no termina entregando un valor 0 de tarea completada, se vuelva a iniciar la descarga las veces que sea necesario. ¿Puedo hacer eso con bash u otro emulador de consola?

Comment: Prueba a crear un demonio, un demonio es un proceso que siempre esta ejecutandose, si da error se auto ejecuta de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], así ganarás tu primera medalla. En cuanto a tu pregunta, es demasiado amplia, trata de acotarla indicando lo que hayas intentado y los problemas encontrados. Saludos

Comment: OK. Gracias @josanangel por la sugerencia y Mauricio Contreras por la crítica constructiva. Volveré con los resultados de lo que intente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, y es bastante simple (cambia `foo.sh` por el comando que quieres ejecutar):

```
while ! foo.sh; do foo.sh && break; done
```

Esto quiere decir que mientras el `foo.sh` no sea exitoso, haga `foo.sh`. Si es exitoso, `break` pára el bucle.

Una otra alternativa mas verbosa, sería:

```
status=1; while [[ $status -ne 0 ]]; do if foo.sh; then status=0; else status=1; fi done
```

O, menos condensado:

```
status=1
while [[ $status -ne 0 ]]; do 
    if foo.sh 
    then 
        status=0 
    else 
        status=1 
    fi 
done
```

La idea es iniciar la variable `status` con valor 1. Después, un bucle `while` que se ejecutará hasta que `status` tenga valor `0`. En cada iteración del bucle, intenta ejecutar `foo.sh`. Si es exitoso, el `status` se pone a `0` y el bucle termina. Si no, se vuelve a ejecutar hasta que esto suceda.

Comment: Acabo de hacer un mini-script llamado "asegurarse.sh" con la primer sugerencia, que es la más simple, y me parece que va a ser el prefijo de casi cada comando que corra a partir de ahora ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma seria utilizar la variable de estado de ejecucion del ejecutable `$?`. Si asumimos que tu foo.sh devuelve un estado estandar en la salida, podrias hacer:

```
foo.sh
while [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; do
    foo.sh;
done
```

asi no necesitas declarar otra variable.